# Image can't start

Tags: docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I can't start image with clear installed Ubuntu. Then trying to install `Nginx` and `PHP` in `Dockerfile`.

I use command `docker-compose up -d` to to prepare and start container, but it always restarting.

Where is the error? Here is my code.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'

services:

    ubuntu:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
            - 80:80
        volumes:
            - ./data:/var/data
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && apt autoremove -y \
    && apt install nginx -y \
    && apt install php -y

CMD ["bash"]
```

Comment: Docker Compose can't run interactive shells; you need to set your image's `CMD` to run something else, probably `nginx`.  Do you want to run these two processes in two separate containers, one using the Docker Hub `nginx` image and the other a custom image `FROM php:fpm`?

Comment: Yes, I now about `Nginx` and `PHP` images in Docker Hub. But I need to run image with clear `Ubuntu` to make custom installations of Nginx and PHP from it's sources. Ready images from Docker Hub not needed now.

Comment: Then you can build two separate images `FROM ubuntu`; but best practice is to run one process per container, and to have the image's `CMD` be to run that as a foreground process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried `docker pull ubuntu` then `docker run ubuntu`. `docker ps` was empty. It means the container starts and ends quickly.
I search `docker inspect ubuntu` and found `"Cmd": "bash"`.

Then I have tried `docker run -it ubuntu` and I had an access to the bash in the ubuntu container. But when I exited, the container closed.

I think you should read and learn from the official nginx for example:
https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/f958fbacada447737319e979db45a1da49123142/mainline/debian/Dockerfile

Your problem is your command: you should use something like
`CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]`

EDIT: I think you should use a Dockerfile for your nginx and another for your php. Then call your images in a docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

It's using the latest Ubuntu image. I had a similar issue except it kept hanging.
Change the first line of your Dockerfile to:
FROM ubuntu:20.04

Comment: Chage to `FROM ubuntu:20.04` but have the same error.

Comment: Remove your restart rule, and try to rebuild. See at which point it freaks out.

Comment: Soo unusual.
Perhaps try to remove the volume and try an older version of ubuntu?